# Reset to Default Unity Login

Tags: kubuntu, login, default

I just installed Kubuntu alongside Ubuntu 12.04, and it changed my login screen. I liked the Ubuntu one and would like to set it back to the default. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command in the terminal-

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

You will get the following screen:

[image: reconfigure]

then enter on `OK` and you will get a screen similar to this with listings as `KDM` and `LIGHTDM`

[image: configure lightdm]

scroll down the navigation to lightdm and press enter.

you will get the ubuntu login screen back.

Comment: @ Gevorg. Thanx for the edit.Can i know how to bring in those greay highlighters??

Comment: Do you need to reboot for this to work?

Comment: @PyRulez yup...