# How to disable lightdm?

Tags: configuration, lightdm

I want to disable lightdm from autostart.
Currenty, I run `service lightdm disable` from terminal, then run `startx`.

`update-rc.d` doesnt help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

lightdm is started by Upstart, not SysV Init.
So update-rc.d doesn't work.

Use

```
 echo  "manual" | sudo tee -a /etc/init/lightdm.override
```

Comment: thank you! By the way, I found [profiles draft for upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Profiles), but it is not implemented so far...

Comment: With this setting I get a black screen when I exit the GUI (after having started it with the `startx` command).

Answer (score 23):

Note that the method described above doesn't work anymore since 15.04 and later, since Upstart was replaced by Systemd. As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services), one can now disable lightdm like this:

## 16.04 upward

```
systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

## 15.04, 15.10

```
systemctl disable lightdm
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work in 16.04.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht you're right, see correction.

Comment: mind that if you do this the system may not boot afterwards (ending up in [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/882385/157358) situation). In that case use the command provided by  Nirmik [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/139020/157358) to reconfigure a display manager

Comment: @glS No, this won't prevent the system from booting. It just disables the display manager ;) so you find a perfectly running shell at ctrl+alt+f2. Here, you can login, and do `sudo service lightdm start` to start lightdm once, or `systemctl enable lightdm.service` to have it start automatically again...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable lightdm to enable gdm or kdm or any other display manager, enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then enter on `ok` and then select from the list your desired display manager.

The same answer with screenshots is given here: [Reset to Default Unity Login](https://askubuntu.com/a/138569/62483)

Answer (score 1):

I just remove the execution bit on the lightdm binary.

`chmod -x /usr/sbin/lightdm`

Then to re-enable it:

`chmod +x /usr/sbin/lightdm`

Comment: This method doesn't work adequately in 16.04. Although LightDM fails to start, the system also gets stuck at startup splash animation indefinitely. TTYs never become available which makes it impossible to log on locally.

Comment: Doing a "sudo systemctl disable lightdm" on a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 AMD64 worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by display-manager... Disable on systemd and you're done.

```
# systemctl disable display-manager        
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service.
```

Comment: This worked for me