# modify start up to boot into cli

Tags: startup

Initially I had the gnome desktop installed and found the graphics card could not support it. I uninstalled the desktop. Now it boots into X graphics mode. How do I make it to boot into CLI mode?

Comment: does this answer your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/139014/how-to-disable-lightdm

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`

```
sudo update-grub
```

**If you are using 11.10 or later** you have lightDM we need to stop it from starting.

```
sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm remove
```