# How to restore Unity login after installing MATE

Tags: login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I installed the MATE desktop to try it out. I did not like it, so I removed it. Now my login screen is terrible. I don't know how to restore the login screen to the original Unity login screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-installing the ubuntu desktop packages and unity, then rebooting.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: I tried the first two commands before I posted. I did not try the third before I posted so thanks for that thought. It did not work, but it is a good command to know.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure lightdm is installed: sudo apt-get install lightdm

Then reconfigure login manager: sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
Check if it has worked. Usually it is enough.

Also see the links: [Reset to Default Unity Login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138561/reset-to-default-unity-login)

[How to restore Ubuntu login screen after lubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install?rq=1)

Comment: I added the lines to the lightdm.conf file. Upon rebooting my computer could only go into low graphics mode, so I only had command line login. Also when I try to reconfigure lightdm, I do not get the screen that asks for the ok option when I use the command. When I use the command literally nothing happens, so I do not know what that means or if it means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with --- Advanced options.

Select the line ending with --- Recovery mode.

After a few moments, your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

Select ---- Network  and  ---- Drop to root shell prompt.

In a terminal run it:

```
sudo -i
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(mate),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'

apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: About to try this next. I tried the other solutions because they were easier, but they did not work. Will get back to you.